# gfortran linking flag for openmp

Tags: compilation, fortran, openmp, gfortran

I'm trying to link multiple .o files using `gfortran`. I've compiled the files like so (in a makefile):

```
gfortran -c -fopenmp file1.f
gfortran -c -fopenmp file2.f
```

Now I'd like to link the files with an option for OpenMP. I know with the Intel compiler the linking flag is `-liomp5`, so to link the files with the Intel compiler one would call:

```
ifort -o a.out file1.o file2.o -liomp5
```

This is obviously not the correct flag for the GNU compiler. What is the correct OpenMP linking flag for `gfortran`?

Comment: With Intel you should link with `-openmp` or `-qopenmp`, your `-liomp5` is the equivalent of `-lgfortran`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `-fopenmp` as well:

```
gfortran -fopenmp -o a.out file1.o file2.o
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Since I'm trying to link mex files for Matlab it's still not quite working, but I'm pretty sure that's a separate issue. I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: On second thought it might be better as a separate question.

Comment: @HH, just link against `libgomp` by adding `-lgomp`. That's what `-fopenmp` does for the linking phase. The `-fopenmp` will fail if Matlab is not using the compiler to link the object files.