# Linking OpenMP with Matlab mex files

Tags: matlab, compilation, fortran, openmp, mex

I'm trying to compile and link some Fortran files with OpenMP for use in Matlab using the mex compiler. Currently I have the compilation and linking in a Makefile:

```
MEX=/usr/local/matlab/bin/mex
FORTRAN = gfortran
FFLAGS = -c -fpic -O3  -fopenmp
MEXLIB = -fopenmp

OBJS=\
file.o\
file2.o\

all: file1 file2 mex

mex: a.out $(OBJS)
$(MEX) -O a.out $(OBJS) $(MEXLIB)

file1: file1.f
$(FORTRAN) $(FFLAGS) file1.f

file2: file2.f
$(FORTRAN) $(FFLAGS) file2.f
```

The compiler flags are in `FFLAGS` and the linking flags are in `MEXLIB`. When I run this using `make all` I get the error:

```
Unknown MEX argument '-fopenmp'.
```

This is a linking issue, since if I remove `-fopenmp` from `MEXLIB` the makefile doesn't give any errors (however the code doesn't seem to run in parallel). I've been told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490944/gfortran-linking-flag-for-openmp) that `-fopenmp` is the correct linking flag to use. Does anyone have any ideas as to what the exact issue is?

EDIT : As was pointed out in the comments below, my problem is similar to others that have been answered, the difference is that I'm attempting to use a Makefile.

Following the instructions from the comments below I tried this the Matlab console

```
mex -v file1.f file2.f FFLAGS="\$FFLAGS -fopenmp" LDFLAGS="\$LDFLAGS -fopenmp"
```

(Note `FFLAGS` instead of `CFLAGS`). This works. Is there any way to incorporate this into my Makefile?

Comment: Also, see [here](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=1795)

Comment: Set `MEXLIB` to `-lgomp`. That should enable linking against the GNU OpenMP runtime library.

Comment: @HristoIliev That works. Why do you need a different flag in the makefile vs in Matlab?

Comment: Because `mex` doesn't seem to understand the `-fopenmp` flag, which is also true for the `ld` linker - that is strictly a GCC/Clang compiler flag. If the compiler is also used to link the final executable, then `-fopenmp` will do as it results in `-lgomp` being passed to the linker.